# How to select all objects sharing a property value with a property value in list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of objects that I want to reload their data.
Like always, I have several options. I wanted just to select these items but encountered this "Additional information": `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

```
// (System.Collections.Generic.List<Item> selectedItems)

System.Collections.Generic.List<Item> items;
var q = from i in db.Items
        where selectedItems.Any(s => s.Id == i.Id)
        select i;
items = q.ToList()
```

the following yields the same, as expected...

```
var q = db.Items.Where(i => selectedItems.Any(si => i.Id == si.Id));
items = q.ToList();
```

I could have reattached each of the objects and call the reload, but then I would have(or not, but I don't know how) to run across the db lot of times to reload their `Navigation Properties`.

The only "fine" solution I've found until now is selecting the `Id`'s of `selectedItems` and then running with it like follows:

```
int[] itemIds = selectedItems.Select(i => i.Id).ToArray();
var q = db.Items.Where(i => itemIds.Any(iId => i.Id == iId)); //Of course `Contains` could be used instead of `Any` here, since `itemIds` is a simple array of integers
items = q.ToList();
```

But is it a necessity or there is a more straight forward, neat or proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

> But is it a necessity or there is a more straight forward, neat or proper way to accomplish this?

Not that I can think of. EF will try and turn your `where` clause into SQL (which is not as easy as you'd think).  When it parses the expression and encounters a call to `Any` on a collection of non-primitive types, it does not know how to generically convert that list into a list of values to put in an into an `in` clause and gives you the error you quoted.

When the source collection is a collection of primitive or enumeration types, it can turn the source collection into a list of values and create an `in` clause. `Contains` does the same thing (it is also shorter is closer to the intent IMHO):

```
var q = db.Items.Where(i => itemIds.Contains(i.Id));
```

Comment: Well, I believe and understand that it's not that simple to build a proper SQL where clause, but as it knows how to convert a collection of primitives into a list for `in` operator, it could have known how to do the same for a specified property of a primitive type... It has all the data, hasn't it?

Comment: @Jyrkka Yes, technically it's possible, but it would require parsing the expression, detecting an equality check, determining that the left operand is a property of the source collection and the right operand is a property of the outer lambda expression, etc. It's much simpler when the source is a collection of primitives.

Comment: Totally agree with you that it's much simpler when the source is a collection of primitives, simpler for framework developers. I think that frameworks in 10 years will be preparing us our morning coffee to make our work simpler and more efficient, that's one of the main reasons(or not?) why we've moved from machine code to low-level and then to high-level languages. So that's an additional step towards our automatically but perfectly made morning coffee.

Comment: So to answer your original question: "Is there a more straight-forward way to do this".  The answer is no.  Might there be in the future?  Possibly, but I'd bet that MS has a host of other features in its backlog that are more valuable that this one.

Comment: Well, I've already understood that your answer is "no.", but please allow me to wait sometime to see if someone comes with an interesting idea before I mark this as an accepted answer. And I'm not asking to implement a solution for this right away, here I'm once again totally agree with you that MS has hands full making vast more valuable features.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought you were arguing that it should already be in the framework.